# Im trying to make a "graphic" printing a certain amount of characters based on array values java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have to make a code thats contain a method that takes a vector of integers as a parameter and, from their values, prints a horizontal bar graph on the screen.
I Just cant print the amount of characters with the value of the string.
Rigth now i have a list in a method:

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
      exibeGraficoDeBarras();
  }
  static void exibeGraficoDeBarras(){
    int lista[]={4,12,10,14,17,9};
    for (int i = 0; i<lista.length; i++ ){
      for (int j = 0; j<lista[i]; j++){
        System.out.print("#");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

And the output should be like this:

"########## 10"

"##### 5"

"####### 7"

Just add the "" cause the formatting

Comment: This isn't enough code.  Show us all of it, not just the Cliff Notes.

Comment: **Hint:** use a `for` loop to print the hash characters.

Comment: But like if i use the for isnt the value of the number that comes after the # going to repet too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 things:

- `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { code goes here }` runs the part in 'code goes here' 10 times. You can put `for` loops in the *code goes here* section too.
- `list[0]` accesses the first item in your list (`10`, in your case). `0` can be `i` too, of course.
- `System.out.print(thingie)` prints things. thingie can be `"#"` to print a hash, for example, or `i`, of course, that works too. `System.out.println()` then finishes the line.

Comment: oh I see, I think I managed to solve it with your tips, but I just can't print the value that comes after the "#" as "#### 4", in my code it looks like this: "#0#1#2#3 ".
can you give me another tip?

Comment: Edit your post with the code that you came up with. Also, you'll want to print the number after the "#" are printed, so just right outside of that inner loop.

Comment: but if I put the variable "j" that I use outside the loop, will it be read?

Comment: No, remember the purpose of that inner loop is just to print out the "#". Once you leave that loop, you are still in the 'i-th' iteration, so you can access list[i] and print it with that outside System.out.println() that you have. Go ahead and test it and don't forget to accept this answer, he pretty much gave you the answer indirectly ;)